# Wordpress: cant derive error

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I've got a strange one going on here. Tried to implement is_wp_error in multiple situations, but it fails. Here's the thing, illustrated with my last attempt:

I want to login a user by `wp_signon()`, check if there are errors and if so, display them.

So I wrote the following lines of code:

```
$user = wp_signon(); 
if(is_wp_error($user)){
     $result = 'Error-' .
     $user->get_error_message(); 
} else {
    $result = 'Login succeed'; 
} 
echo $result;
```

The strange thing is, `is_wp_error()` doesn't return false (so there is an error). But `$user->get_error_message();` is empty.

Tried it in different actions. When debugging, `echo is_wp_error();` returns 0.
`var_dump(wp_is_error());` returns empty arrays.

Furthermore, even when valid credentials are given, is_wp_error() still returns true. Also when testing in other circumstances (and on a clean WP installation)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look through the `wp_signon()` code (located at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/user.php#L0 )

Looks like the error is blanked out if a blank username or password is passed in.  (lines 56 and 57 of that file.)

Comment: Thanks. Edited my question; the error still occurs when everything really is valid, strange enough. 
And what I can see in the codex, when nothing is passed, there should be some message. Should it be a bug then? Hard to imagine...

Comment: Another note: this did solved the problem. Turns out you've have to check for errors not by empty(). Thanks!